# Openbox keyboard shortcut to python program

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

I have a custom python script that I woud like to run when a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> is pressed.

I have made the customization as follows in `lxqt-rc.xml` and run

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

but I don't see anything happening. I can confirm that I have been able to run other actions in the past with the same keyboard shortcut. I can also confirm that I can run the said python command directly from the terminal without any issues.

```
    <keybind key="C-A-w">
      <action name="ShowMenu">
        <!--<menu>client-list-combined-menu</menu> -->
    <command>python3 ~/bin/ShowWindowList/ShowWindowList.py</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

Not sure if this detail is relevant but the python program above will display a custom GUI which lists the windows in all the desktops and allows for searching by window title. Should I do something else (like fork the python process) to get this to work?

Comment: Try providing an absolute path to `python3` and your script (the problem might be the expansion of `~`

Comment: @Panki I have tried that too but no luck...